# How to fix Fancybox called multiple times after opened?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, popup, fancybox

My web page work fine, but when I check Network it showed the fancybox do multiple request.
Here is my situtation open_bp_wip_detail runs 3 times
[F12 Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPtAA.png)
Here my codes

```
<div>
<%= link_to 'Detail',{:action => :open_bp_wip_detail, :device => 'device_01'}, {:class => "fancy"} %>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fancy').addClass('fancybox.ajax');
});
</script>
```

Let fancybox only request once.

Comment: First, you have to specify what version of Fancybox are you using. Then, I have never heard of such issue, it's quite incredible that it happened to you and no one else, therefore you should provide a live demo where this issue could be observed.

Comment: My code is using Fancybox2.